# Using One Variable Parameter Inside Another Method

Tags: java, methods, parameters, return

So I'm trying to have some methods for my class called test, and the methods get a variable from the driver. There are some methods that are supposed to get the return value from the getter methods.

Main Class:

```
public class test {
    public int setSpeed(int speed) {
        return speed;
    }
    public void getSpeed() {
        //I don't know what to put here
    }
}
```

Driver:

```
public class testDriver {
    test b = new test();
    b.setSpeed(25);
    System.out.println("The Speed is: ", b.getSpeed());
}
```

I have to use a regular int in the driver; I cannot assign its value to a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `test` class should look like this:

```
public class test {
    private int speed;
    public void setSpeed(int speed) {
        this.speed = speed;
    }
    public int getSpeed() {
        return this.speed;
    }
}
```

Basically you are not suppose to return something when you are setting a value. You are suppose the return a value when you are getting something

Comment: Yeah thank you so much, this makes a lot more sense!